# Calling libiptc API from a separate thread in a C program throws segmentation fault

Tags: c, multithreading, iptables, iptc

I am working on performing iptables update through a custom c program using libiptc. The requirement is to invoke iptc APIs from a separate thread every 2 seconds.

I have written a simple C program to try out invoking of iptc APIs from a separate thread. The c program is pasted below.

```
/*** thread_iptc.c ***/

#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void* thread_func(void* unused)
{
        struct iptc_handle *handle = NULL;
        char *table = "filter";

        while (1)
        {
                printf("\nthread_func(): While loop.\n");
                handle = iptc_init(table);
                if (handle) {
                        printf("thread_func(): handle is not NULL.\n");
                        iptc_free(handle);
                }
                else
                        printf("thread_func(): handle is NULL.\n");

                sleep(2);
        }

        return NULL;
}


int main()
{
        struct iptc_handle *handle = NULL;
        char *table = "filter";
        pthread_t thread_id;

        handle = iptc_init(table);
        if (handle) {
                printf("main(): handle is not NULL.\n");
                iptc_free(handle);
        }
        else
                printf("main(): handle is NULL.\n");


        pthread_create(&thread_id, NULL, &thread_func, NULL);
        pthread_join(thread_id, NULL);

        return 0;
}
```

The problem, I am facing is that call to both `iptc_init(`) and `iptc_free()` works well when called from `main` function. However, call to `iptc_free()` fails with "Segmentation Fault" when called from `thread_func()`.

Program Output:

```
# ./test 
main(): handle is not NULL.

thread_func(): While loop.
thread_func(): handle is not NULL.
Segmentation fault
```

Compilation:

```
# gcc -o test thread_iptc.c -lpthread -lext4 -lext6 -lip4tc -lip6tc -liptc -lxtables -ldl
```

GDB Backtrace

```
#0  0x00007ffff79be303 in iptc_free () from /lib64/libip4tc.so.0
#1  0x00000000004007f3 in thread_func ()
#2  0x00007ffff7bc77e1 in start_thread () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#3  0x00007ffff6efb8ed in clone () from /lib64/libc.so.6
```

Am I missing something during compilation or while invoking a new thread?

Comment: What happens if you don't call `iptc_init` in main? Or call it with a different table name? Does it make the thread call work, or work crash on the second time (or just crash the same way)?

Comment: Tried both ("Removing iptc_init call in main", "using different table name"). Result is same. Crashing the same way.

Comment: Perhaps the iptc library has some per-thread element. Have you ever tried to call iptc_init inside the second thread instead of in the main one?

Comment: Another aproach to get insight, would be to use a debug version of the iptc library (or build one if none is available).

Comment: I added #include <unistd.h> and #include <libiptc/libiptc.h> to your code and compiled without warnings. On my x86_64 debian system it works perfectly. I compiled with those switches: gcc -Wall -pthread -liptc -o thread_iptc thread_iptc.c